# Simple Framework - parse list from tags with counter

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

In my map project I use [simple-framework xml parser](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and I need to parse nasty "xml" which is a variation of the GPS data. The format is similar to:

```
<data>
    <name>SL12-34</name>
    <planename>C-172 SP-TZI</planename>
    ...
    <track>
        <rt0>
            <lat>49,23844</lat>
            <lon>18,034135</lon>
            <name>EPKM</name>
            <course>48</course>
            <distance>18,568</distance>
        </rt0>
        <rt1>
            <lat>49,350014</lat>
            <lon>18,228509</lon>
            <name> 2</name>
            <course>0</course>
            <distance>49,004</distance>
        </rt1>
        ...
        <rt18>
            <lat>49,350014</lat>
            <lon>18,221422</lon>
            <name> 19</name>
            <course>227</course>
            <distance>18,197</distance>
        </rt18>
    </track>
</data>
```

My Waypoint class:

```
@Root(name = "rt????")
public class Waypoint {
    @Element
    public double lat;

    @Element
    public double lon;

    @Element
    public String name;

    @Element
    public String course;

    @Element
    public double distance;
}
```

And my question is - how main class must looks like to parse this xml (using a [simple-framework xml parser](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) ) to get a `List<Waypoint>`? I have no concept here :/

Comment: Please show an _actual_ sample of the input XML. It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but perhaps XPath is what you are looking for?

Comment: I expanded my question - maybe now will be easier to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not do this using a data binding framework. You can do this surely by stepping through the DOM (manually or by XPath) or you use [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) instead of data binding. (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project)

```
import java.util.List;
import org.xmlbeam.XBProjector;
import org.xmlbeam.annotation.XBRead;
public class ReadWayPoints {

    public interface WayPoint {
        @XBRead("./lat using #,#")
        double getLat();
        @XBRead("./lon using #,#")
        double getLon();
        @XBRead("./name")
        String getName();
        @XBRead("./course") 
        String getCourse();
        @XBRead("./distance using #,#")
        double getDistance();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<WayPoint> waypoints = new XBProjector().io().url("res://data.xml").evalXPath("/data/track/*").asListOf(WayPoint.class);
        for (WayPoint wp:waypoints) {
            System.out.println(wp.getName()+" "+wp.getLat()+":"+wp.getLon());                
        }
    }
}
```

After removing the `...` in your example, this program prints out:

```
EPKM 49.23844:18.034135
 2 49.350014:18.228509
 19 49.350014:18.221422
```

Why does this work? By using the expression `/data/track/*` you are projecting every direct child element of `<track>` to the projection interface `WayPoint`. You could even add a method `@XBRead("name()") String getName()` to the interface to get the current element name.